# How to implement a new drush topic?

Tags: drush

I just read the [Drush Topic - A Wealth of Information](https://pantheon.io/blog/drush-topic-wealth-information) article about the topic section in drush commands and I have added this topic to my drush commands:

```
  $items['docs-onlyone'] = array(
    'description' => 'Info about Only One.',
    'hidden' => TRUE,
    'topic' => TRUE,
    'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH,
    'callback' => 'drush_print_file',
    'callback arguments' => array(dirname(__FILE__) . '/README.txt'),
  );
```

The problem is that the only way to see the new topic in the topic list once I use the `drush topic` command is if I place my onlyone.drush.inc file inside the .drush folder.

Is this normal? I can't see the topic if I have my onlyone.drush.inc file inside my module folder.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have selected the Drupal site that your module is in (e.g. with an @alias, via --root and --uri, or cd /path/to/drupal/sites/default), and also ensure that the module is enabled. Otherwise, Drush will not find and load the file.

Comment: if I use drush help mycommand I can see the topic section, the module is enable, but I can't see the topic in the drush topic command, if I call drush docs-onlyone the command works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a Drush bug. Try different major versions of Drush, and report results in the Drush issue queue.